# set custom boto configuration file other than default for boto3

Tags: python, ubuntu, boto3

I'm not getting any option to set custom configuration file location with boto3. I can use credentials from default location.

My use case is, there are different IAM users and have different set of credentials so each one should be able to use their own credentials without changing default configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wanted something similar in boto3 to what we have in boto2, boto.config.load_credential_file('file_name')

Comment: use: aws configuration profile ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will help:
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html#credentials

You can set different credentials for different users.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use python module `configparser`

Example will show to check status of RDS instance and store your aws credentials file anywhere it will work.

```
import configparser
import boto3

class CheckStatus():

    rds_instance_name = 'rds_instnace_name'
    aws_config_file = 'aws_config.ini'

    def __init__(self, aws_config):

        self.aws_config = aws_config
        self.client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=self.aws_config['default']['region'],
                                   aws_access_key_id=self.aws_config['default']['aws_access_key_id'],
                                   aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_config['default']['aws_secret_access_key'])

    def check_rds_status(self):
        current_status = None

        response = self.client.describe_db_instances(
            DBInstanceIdentifier=self.rds_instance_name)
        current_status = response['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceStatus']
        print(current_status)


def get_config():
    aws_config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    aws_config.read(CheckStatus.aws_config_file)
    return aws_config

obj = CheckStatus(get_config())

obj.check_rds_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is eminently doable. You can achieve this by assigning some keyword arguments that are passed through the `boto3.Session` object, e.g.,

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="AAAA",
    aws_secret_access_key="BBBBB",
    region_name="mordor"
)
```

Then just use your session object as normal:

```
s3_object = session.resource('s3') # or whatever
```

So all you'll need to do is fill some python data structure with the credentials you want (populated from your custom configuration file), and pass them into that `boto3.Session` object.

Comment: The question was how to specify a custom location for a configuration file, not how to pass credentials directly to boto3 session.